# How to save the edited file in prime ng p-editor without HTML conent(</p><p>}</p><p>//<br></br>)

Tags: angular, primeng

I am Not able to save the file with proper format after editing in the p-editor.  It is saving along with some HTML Content like `(<p></p><br></br><b>///)`.

I am trying to edit the file in the editor, when I edit and save the same file , result in I am seeing some html code like `<br></br><p></p>/)`.

Comment: Please add code snippet so, we can understand , where exactly you get the issue.

Comment: <p-editor   [(ngModel)]="fileContent">   
      </p-editor>.   This is Editor code,  fileContent contain the result of the file.
     reader.fileReader(file: File){
   this.fileData =file;
    let fileReader:FileReader=new FileReader();
    let self=this;
    fileReader.onloadend=function(x){
      self.fileContent=fileReader.result;
    }
    fileReader.readAsText( this.fileData );
  }